# Creating Custom Simple Mapi DLL, fails when executing

Tags: c++, dll, attachment, mapi

i need to create small dll to intercept simple mapi calls and send files via:

file->Send to as attachment (in excel, word, acrobat reader...)
or via explorer->rightclickmenu->Send to->Mail recipient

to attach to gmail.

after reading this:

[Mapi32.dll Stub Registry Settings (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee909492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Mapi32 Stub Library (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee909493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and searching here on stackoverflow and other webs i have created one very small dll using code::blocks that shows me information for investigating the process.

I have installed it on registry correctly like indicated in previous links on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\SimpMapi.

I have selected on my win xp pro in control panel->Internet options my SimpMapi client.

when i open excel write some cells and go to File->Send like attachment dll shows me that first calls MapiLogon, second calls MapiSendMail and third when i close excel it calls MapiLogoff, but then it throws an error and closes excel.exe.

If i try it from explorer window right clicking one file and SendTo->Mail recipient it calls directly MapiSendMail and when i click on ok in MsgBox it throws an error and closes explorer.exe

Could you help me to find out what is wrong.

This is the mail.h file:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

// Todo lo necesario a incluir por mapi.h
#define SUCCESS_SUCCESS         0
#define MAPI_E_USER_ABORT       1
#define MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE    3

typedef unsigned long FLAGS;
typedef unsigned long LHANDLE;
typedef unsigned long FAR *LPLHANDLE, FAR *LPULONG;

typedef struct {
  ULONG ulReserved;
  ULONG ulRecipClass;
  LPSTR lpszName;
  LPSTR lpszAddress;
  ULONG ulEIDSize;
  LPVOID lpEntryID;
} MapiRecipDesc, *lpMapiRecipDesc;

typedef struct {
  ULONG ulReserved;
  ULONG flFlags;
  ULONG nPosition;
  LPSTR lpszPathName;
  LPSTR lpszFileName;
  LPVOID lpFileType;
} MapiFileDesc, *lpMapiFileDesc;

typedef struct {
  ULONG ulReserved;
  LPSTR lpszSubject;
  LPSTR lpszNoteText;
  LPSTR lpszMessageType;
  LPSTR lpszDateReceived;
  LPSTR lpszConversationID;
  FLAGS flFlags;
  lpMapiRecipDesc lpOriginator;
  ULONG nRecipCount;
  lpMapiRecipDesc lpRecips;
  ULONG nFileCount;
  lpMapiFileDesc lpFiles;
} MapiMessage, *lpMapiMessage;


/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);

extern "C" ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPILogon(ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,LPSTR lpszProfileName,LPSTR lpszPassword,FLAGS flFlags,ULONG ulReserved,LPLHANDLE lplhSession);
extern "C" ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPILogoff(LHANDLE lhSession,ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,FLAGS flFlags,ULONG ulReserved);
extern "C" ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPISendDocuments(ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,LPSTR lpszDelimChar,LPSTR lpszFilePaths,LPSTR lpszFileNames,ULONG ulReserved);
extern "C" ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPISendMail(LHANDLE lhSession,ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,lpMapiMessage lpMessage,FLAGS flFlags,ULONG ulReserved);

#endif
```

This is the main.cpp file:

```
#include "main.h"

// a sample exported function
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPILogon(ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,LPSTR lpszProfileName,LPSTR lpszPassword,FLAGS flFlags,ULONG ulReserved,LPLHANDLE lplhSession)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "MAPILogon", "MAPILogon", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
}
ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPILogoff(LHANDLE lhSession,ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,FLAGS flFlags,ULONG ulReserved)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "MAPILogoff", "MAPILogoff", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
}
ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPISendDocuments(ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,LPSTR lpszDelimChar,LPSTR lpszFilePaths,LPSTR lpszFileNames,ULONG ulReserved)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "MAPISendDocuments", "MAPISendDocuments", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
}
ULONG DLL_EXPORT MAPISendMail(LHANDLE lhSession,ULONG_PTR ulUIParam,lpMapiMessage lpMessage,FLAGS flFlags,ULONG ulReserved)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "MAPISendMail", "MAPISendMail", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
}
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Jorge

Comment: Installed Affixa software (for attaching files directly to gmail, yahoo, etc.). This software uses mapi2xml.dll as a mapi dll. This DLL exports also Simple Mapi calls. Investigated its registry settings and i could use that .dll changing its exe redirector, but i think it is not legal if a install it on all computers of work. This is the reason that i would like to program my own c++ simple dll to intercept MAPI calls and redirect it to my exe file to create mime message, attach file and upload to gmail as a draft. I have done it using Autoit+php (for using IMAP+SSL). Now i need to use MAPI.

Comment: The only reason to use MAPI is for integrating in excel, word, acrobat reader and other software that has the standard "file->Sent to" to attach the document thas is being edited to a new message, my users used outlook and now we tried Gmail for business, they like to attach from that applications.

Comment: solved the problem, see following link http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/103010/ then problema was incorrect calling convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In link: [Creating Custom Simple Mapi DLL, throws error when executing](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/103010/)

Andy helped me to solve the problem that was incorrect calling convention.

Adding WINAPI to all my Simple MAPI function declarations and definitions it worked, example:

```
extern "C" ULONG DLL_EXPORT WINAPI MAPILogon( // etc
```

Then the problem was that my exported functions were exported with declarations.

To correct this in code::blocks you have to add in:

Main menu: Project -> Build options -> GNU GCC Compiler -> Linker settings -> Other linker options: -Wl,--kill-at

Thanks!