# clang [bcc32c Warning] redeclaration should not add 'dllexport' attribute

Tags: clang, c++builder, clang++

I am creating a DLL and exporting a SimpleMAPI DLL function and one of the functions signature is as following:

`extern "C" ULONG __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI MAPISendMail(LHANDLE lhSession, ULONG_PTR ulUIParam, lpMapiMessage lpMessage, FLAGS flFlags, ULONG ulReserved);`

I am using C++ Builder, using clang compiler. Compiler issues warning:

`[bcc32c Warning]: redeclaration of 'MAPISendMail' should not add 'dllexport' attribute mapi.h(262): previous declaration is here`

It compiles and works, but I am bothered by this warning. Can it be avoided?

Comment: As the warning says, `MAPISendMail()` is already *declared* in `<mapi.h>`, and you are trying to *redeclare* it differently. If you want to *use* SimpleMAPI, you include `<mapi.h>`. But if you want to *implement* SimpleMAPI, don't include `<mapi.h>`. Copy the few declarations your function(s) need (`lpMapiMessage`, etc) into your own code. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718855)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks - it is not intuitive but I have resolved the problem. If you want to make this into an answer, please do, if not, I will make one myself after a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RemyLebeau pointed out, the warnings happened because I included <mapi.h> header.

If MAPI DLL is being created (creating your own DLL that other programs will use or exporting MAPI functions), so if one is implementing MAPI support in their own program, then the required structures and `#define` are copied from the original `mapi.h` file into a custom header file which is then included. `#define` such as `FLAGS` or `MapiMessage` struct.

If MAPI is being used (so using calling MAPI functions from other DLL, or other programs) then <mapi.h> is included.

So after creating a custom `mapidefs.h` file which only contained required structures and #define, the problem is now solved.

There is also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718855/creating-custom-simple-mapi-dll-fails-when-executing) on StackOverflow as well.